# Randomising itertools.combinations

Tags: python, random, combinations, python-itertools

I have a list, `l1`, which I have generated all combinations of length 2 using itertools.combinations. I intend to loop through these combinations, and perform an operation on them. For simplicity, this code simply prints combination `a`.

```
import itertools

l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
for a in itertools.combinations(l1,2):
    print(a)
```

Is there any way to randomise the order that the combinations are looped through? `random.shuffle` does not appear to work, as itertools.combinations has no length.

Comment: See also [`more_itertools.random_combination`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.random_combination)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not save the combinations as a variable and then shuffle?:

```
import itertools
import random

l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
combs = list(itertools.combinations(l1,2))
random.shuffle(combs)
for a in combs:
    print(a)
```

Comment: This will work, but only for sufficiently small combinations that can be converted to lists.